# Query parameters generate 400 in website configuration on root URL

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Our website is getting mentioned on Twitter and people are running it through URL shorteners. In some cases this appends utm query parameters to the URL like so:

http://coreos.com/?utm_source=buffer&utm_campaign=Buffer&utm_content=buffer1b61d&utm_medium=twitter

However, going to that URL will generate a 400 and give an XML body!

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>Invalid argument.</Message>
<Details>Invalid query parameter: utm_source</Details>
</Error>
```

This works fine on pages with a path however:

http://coreos.com/docs/sdk/?utm_source=buffer&utm_campaign=Buffer&utm_content=buffer1b61d&utm_medium=twitter

How do I configure Google Cloud Storage to work properly?

Comment: This looks like an issue with Google Cloud Storage. I don't think there's a config setting you can set that will fix, unfortunately.

Comment: We're working on a fix for this issue.

Comment: We've fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with how Cloud Storage handled URL parameters on the root object, because the API uses the same domain as live traffic.  Things have been updated to ignore this sort of unused parameter in buckets with a web config.